# Fontforge: How to "remove overlaps" making work

Tags: svg, fonts, latex, overlap, fontforge

I create an arrow in TikZ and convert it to svg (`pdf2svg file.pdf file.svg`). 
Then I import my `output.svg` into *FontForge* and choose there `Element --> Overlap --> remove`. 
Finally I put the character `\symbol{65}` into a tex-document, but I have still these 'overlaps' in form from white space inside the sign.

Could somebody help me to create the sign correctly?

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=15mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\myfont}[Scale=1]{myfont.ttf}

\begin{document}
\textbf{For output and svg-conversion}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5mm]
\draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (5,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\textbf{Input from myfont.ttf}
\myfont\Huge\symbol{65}
\end{document}
```

**Working Folder with**

```
test.tex
test.pdf
output.svg
myfont.ttf   (only 1 character at No. 65)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j2TEubR7IMu91wA4G7Mda4bqG9ddP5sg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try with this .svg https://pastebin.com/MzZNNdVX ?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  This looks very good. I can use it to create the straight arrows. However, I need a working method to transfer that to other (curvilinear) arrows.

Comment: I'll write something up how to postprocess the svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of arrows is not too big, you can post-process the svg file with inkscape

1. select all and `ungroup` a couple of times

   [image]
2. now use `Stroke to Path` option

   [image]
3. and finally `union` all the shapes
   [image]

This will result in an svg file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   xml:space="preserve"
   width="321.26001"
   height="132.284"
   viewBox="0 0 321.26001 132.284"
   sodipodi:docname="document.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 5c3e80d, 2017-08-06"><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6" /><sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="640"
     inkscape:window-height="480"
     id="namedview4"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.2729107"
     inkscape:cx="160.63"
     inkscape:cy="62.842265"
     inkscape:current-layer="g10" /><g
     id="g10"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     inkscape:label="document"
     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,132.284)"><path
       style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:medium;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-position:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-alternates:normal;font-feature-settings:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;writing-mode:lr-tb;direction:ltr;text-orientation:mixed;dominant-baseline:auto;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;white-space:normal;shape-padding:0;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;opacity:1;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:18.89785385;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate"
       d="M 206.78906 41.976562 L 217.82617 56.693359 L 66.140625 56.693359 L 66.140625 75.591797 L 217.82617 75.591797 L 206.78906 90.308594 L 255.11914 66.142578 L 206.78906 41.976562 z "
       transform="matrix(0.75000002,0,0,-0.75000002,0,99.213002)"
       id="path18" /></g></svg>
```

Comment: Aha, ok. I think, I can work with that. Did you use a stealth-arrow from inkscape or from TikZ?

Comment: @cis I used the first part of the code from your question to generate the image, then opened it with inkskape

Comment: Ah ok, I understand.